# PHPExcel +Codeigniter: Invalid character

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpexcel

I am trying to export excel file using PHPExcel and Codeigniter  as [this](http://www.ahowto.net/php/easily-integrateload-phpexcel-into-codeigniter-framework.).

I can't download the excel file but output is showing in console with an invalid character.
This is the screen shot of console output.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to open the file using MS excel in order to make sure that it is a valid file? i suspect it is, and regarding the attached image this is because terminals cannot be used to view excel files and hence they are being treated as binary ones.

Comment: i cant see anything? :(

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash : i have tried to force but not downloading.and am using open office calc

Comment: @ferozakbar there is nothing to see only invalid charecter

Comment: If your issue is only to check the validity of the file then just get it from the server using any tool "scp, ftp, wget ... etc" then validate it using your openoffice tool

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash can u expail more clearly

Comment: Do you know how to get a regular text file from the server to your computer? if yes then do the same with the excel file, when you have it on your computer try opening it using openoffice in order to check the validity of the file.

Comment: you have posted this before editing http://i.stack.imgur.com/1fDpp.png

Comment: @ferozakbar ya i changed it

Comment: Do you actually need to create an Excel file, or would it suffice to use a delimited text format (such as CSV) that Excel will open?

Comment: @NishamMahsin: To create a CSV, have you considered using [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html) or [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. First solution

I had the same probleme.
Use the class developped by Eliselab

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Export-to-Excel-2013

For export you just need to put this on your controller.

```
$this->load->library('export');
$this->load->model('YourModel');

$result = $this->YourModel->YourQueryFunction();
$this->export->to_excel($result, 'nameForFile');
```

### 2. Second way

If you want to use PHPExcel try to put the same charset on all your pages,
File charset & content charset. (UTF-8)

Put this on your file header :

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

And change the type of file in `UTF-8 Without Bom`

On Nodepadd++ go to :

> Click on "Format" 
>   Select "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM"

I hope it will help you.

Comment: can you explain more detail second way.i am newb

Comment: I have edit my answer. See how change the charset :)

Comment: can you upload the screen or the error. I would like to see that ^^

Comment: What sort of data you try to export ?

Comment: in my example application hardcoded data like the link in question. but in future from mysql table

Comment: I know this does not answer your question, but when I used Export to Excel 2013 EliseLab I have not had any problems. Verify your encodage file. If you have these characters it's cause of the charset i think.

Comment: excel file is created in file with no problem.but users cant forcefully download

Comment: @NishamMahsin You can write the file to the output buffer so that the use can directly download.

Comment: ya .what am doing is writing to output buffer.for testing i tried direct saving to file.it works fine.. But not working. 
$obj->save('php://output')

Comment: i am accepting this as answer for ur effort. somewhat ok.

Answer (score 2):

I have created excel files with the following code and it works. Please make sure you set the headers correctly.

```
    $this->load->library('Excel');

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Creator name");
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("Creator name");
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("File Title");
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("Content Subject");
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("Content Description");
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Sheet Title');
    $filename = 'sample_' . time() . '.xls'; //save our workbook as this file name
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"'); //tell browser what's the file name
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');

    exit;
```